# Why does getting an exported function's pointer directly return an address in the same module?

Tags: c++, dll, direct3d, dll-injection

I'm using a classic setup for hooking d3d9 functions: Injecting a DLL then getting target function addresses and patching them with a JMP instruction.

However I have run into something I don't quite understand. Consider the following snippet from the DLL I'll inject into the target process:

```
HMODULE ModuleBasedOnGetAPI = NULL;
HMODULE ModuleBasedOnAddress = NULL;

ModuleBasedOnGetAPI = GetModuleHandleA("d3d9.dll");
D3D9Create_Original = (t_D3D9Create)GetProcAddress(ModuleBasedOnGetAPI,
                      "Direct3DCreate9");

D3D9Create_Original2 = &Direct3DCreate9;
GetModuleHandleExA(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS |
                   GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT,
                   (LPCSTR)D3D9Create_Original2, &ModuleBasedOnAddress);

char ModuleBasedOnGetAPI_path[_MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameA(ModuleBasedOnGetAPI, ModuleBasedOnGetAPI_path, _MAX_PATH);

char ModuleBasedOnAddress_path[_MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameA(ModuleBasedOnAddress, ModuleBasedOnAddress_path,
                  _MAX_PATH);
```

Where D3D9Create_Original and D3D9Create_Original2 are function pointers of type:

```
IDirect3D9*(__stdcall *)(UINT)
```

Basically I did the usual GetModuleHandle call and got that file's name. And then I got the function pointer and used `GetModuleHandleEx` with the `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` to basically determine which DLL that address comes from.

So `ModuleBasedOnGetAPI_path` is the actual path of the d3d9.dll file. 
While `ModuleBasedOnAddress_path` seems to be the path of my DLL from which this snippet was taken.

So why is that? why does the `Direct3DCreate9` function reside both in my DLL and in d3d9.dll? Does it have something todo with the fact that I linked d3d9.lib when building my DLL?

Comment: You may want to consider using a signature scan to hook DX9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your build configuration (i.e. Debug or Release)? Looks like compiler's optimization also matters here.

For Release build, I cannot reproduce the issue - the two addresses are the same.

For Debug build, your assumption is correct. It is because when you reference `Direct3DCreate9` directly in your code, you are the calling the stub code in your own module, which will further get the real `Direct3DCreate9` address from the [Import Address Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format).

To better illustrate the concept:

[image]

Please pay attention that Visual Studio already tells you that the two addresses are from different modules.

Lets take a look at the address `0x008f1249`:

[image]

It's no more than a `jmp`. Take a look at `0x08FCFAD` further:

[image]

Another jump. And finally `0x0913220`:

[image]

Please recall the value of `D3D9Create_Original` - here is the real address which is the same with `D3D9Create_Original`.

Comment: My build configuration was debug. I changed it to release and it did return the same address!  Thank you for the information!